# Interview: Top N integers in a List over a period of time

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I was recently asked a interview question to find Top `N(10,20)` integers in a `List` over a period of time. The `List` is dynamically added elements over a period of regular interval like 5 seconds. Could you please tell how to use the correct data structure and algorithm for this problem..

Comment: what does Top N(10, 20) integers mean? top 10 to 20 integers in a list?

Comment: did you tried something? or you totally failed in the interview and need us to succeed next time?

Comment: make sorted list storing top N points w/ timestamps when they arrived. when new point arrived - you clean up outdated points if needed (if they should expire) add new point to the proper place and remove lowest point from it.

Comment: @iced: That's a fairly expensive data structure. Inserting into a sorted list is O(N), as is removing. Care to explain how you'd improve on that?

Comment: there is no better way but to keep current result and adjust it on new data

Comment: @iced: There are better ways. You could create a queue and a pairing heap. As each data item comes in, you remove the oldest one from the queue and from the heap, and insert the new one in both data structures. Heap insertion and removal is O(log N). Queue insertion and removal is O(1). Getting the top M items from the heap would be O(M log N), which is a bit slower than getting them from the sorted list, but the query is typically infrequent whereas insertion and removal are very frequent.

Comment: it's same with sorted linked list

Comment: If you only keep the top 20 elements then inserting into a sorted array should be fine. The O(n) complexity of the operation doesn't matter if n is bounded by a constant, and 20 is quite a small constant.

Answer (score 1):

Such questions normally are not very sophisticated.

10 highest of last 20 entries: An ArrayList of at most 20 elements, adding at the end may remove one at the beginning. Then add them to a new SortedSet (like TreeSet), and take the first 10 on a reversed order. See @iced

If a Queue would fit, nice. (It does not entirely.) But the most important point is correctness. Seeing you cannot sort that ArrayList. That less than 10 top numbers may appear when many duplicates. Points for adding concurrency guards and such.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Priority Queue/ Max heap.

Comment: This is more comment then answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead); instead, provide answers according to [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)